# Exception: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A

Tags: java, angularjs, json, http

I'm getting an exception while trying to send an object from my angular service to the RestController:

> 2017-02-26 12:08:46.612  WARN 2766 --- [nio-8080-exec-6].w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: N/A
>       at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1e2c3f38; line: 1, column: 117] (through reference chain: com.model.Project["status"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A
>       at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1e2c3f38; line: 1, column: 117] (through reference chain: com.model.Project["status"])

My service function:

```
self.saveProjectToDB = function(project) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/project/save',
        data: project,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    });

};
```

Object being sent:

```
12:20:17.182 Object { id: "58b2af85db91990ace5b1e20", title: "ffs", deadline: null, owner: null, leader: null, status: null, skills: null, resources: Array[3], $$hashKey: "object:26" } 1 resourceCtrl.js:41:4
```

My RestController function:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> saveProject(@RequestBody Project project) {
    if(project == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Body missing!");
    }
    Project savedProject = projectService.saveProject(project);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(savedProject);
}
```

And my model class:

```
@Document(collection = "project")
public class Project  {


@Id
private String id;
private String title;
private String deadline;
private String owner;
private String leader;
private String status;
@DBRef
private List<Skill> skills;
@DBRef(lazy=true)
private List<Resource> resources;

/* Constructor and getters/setters */
```

The response status I'm getting is 400 which suggests that the RequestBody project is null.

**EDIT**:

Okay so it only works if status != null, which is strange because all the other variables are allowed to be null.

Comment: Your JSON contains a "customer" field which I can't find in your Project class.

Comment: Oh right sorry, I removed it in this example because it was irrelevant, ill remove it in the object as well.